# how to increase HD size of Linux running on VMware

Tags: linux, vmware, diskspace

I have already increased the size by going into VMWARE Workstation settings ->Hardisk to 34GB. But I cant able to relocate it inside the Ubunto running inside the VMware.

I want to increase the size of /dev/sda1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to expand hard disk size using VMware:**
To increase the virtual disk from the command line:

1. Open a command prompt. For more information, see [how to open command prompt](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1003892).
2. Navigate to the product's installation directory. [See how to do that](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1003897)
3. Type `vmware-vdiskmanager -x 100Gb vm.vmdk` and press Enter(Replace 100Gb with the actual size of virtual disk that you want. You can also specify Kb and Mb.)
4. [Follow this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1004071)

And, I guess you've tried this(from GUI):

1. Select the virtual machine from the Inventory.
2. Click **Edit Virtual Machine Settings**.
3. Click **Hard Disk**.
4. Click **Utilities > Expand**, enter the new size, then click **Expand**.
5. Again, [follow this one](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1004071)

**How to expand hard disk size inside Ubuntu(using gparted tool):**
What about expanding inside Ubuntu, I guess you should try `gparted` or similar tool. How to do that, go [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)

To open `gparted` do the following:

1. Install it by typing `sudo apt-get install gparted`
2. Run it by pressing `Alt+F2`, and type there `gparted`

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem and fixed it using `gparted`.

After increasing the size by going into VMWARE Workstation settings -> Hardisk,

- Run your Virtual Machine.
- Open Terminal
- Install `gparted`

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

- After installation, open `gparted`
  [image]
- You will see the space unallocated(1), this is the space that you indicated in your vmware workstation settings (5GB in my case)
  [image]
- Select your existing partition(1), then click the `Resize/Move` icon(2).
  [image]
- Simply, move the resize handle up to your desired new size(1), click `Resize`(2).
  [image]
- Do not forget to click the `Check` icon to Apply all operation made.
  [image]
- and that's it! You have expanded your VM HD Size.

Try it out, the app's ui made it easier to use. I used this method in my VMWare Workstation for Ubuntu 18.04. (might work as well with Ubuntu 20.x)

Comment: For me this is not working. Despite the space showing up as unallocated as expected, after selecting the existing partition and clicking `Resize/Move`, the space cannot be allocated. Minimum size and maximum size show the same value.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had to unmount the disk to increase the unalocated spaced. It worked

Comment: Sometimes the GUI approach beats the CLI approach. The check icon looked slightly different in v1.2.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note: To edit the hard disk size we must remove existing snapshots, so be careful

First, remove any existing snapshots and edit the Hard disk size and launch the VM

### COMMANDS

Run below commands as ROOT user

```
$ fdisk -l
```

```
$ gparted
```

=> Select the File System 'linux-swap' and click on 'Swapoff'

=> Select the File System 'extended' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the right arrow to full-right, then click 'resize/move'

=> Select the File System 'linux-swap' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the left-and-right symbol to full-right, then click 'resize/move' and click 'OK'

=> Select the File System 'extended' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the left arrow to full-right and select Align to 'Cylinder' from drop-down menu, then click 'resize/move'

=> Select the File System 'ext4' then do right click and select 'resize/move' and drag the right arrow to full-right, then click 'Resize'

=> Then either click on 'check symbol' or go to edit and select 'Apply All Operations' then click 'Apply ' and 'Close' (Ignore warnings)

```
$ reboot
```

```
$ fdisk -l
```

### References

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwpzYlfKnrY

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/extending-partitions-on-linux-vmware-virtual-machines/

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Virtual-Machine-Guest-OS-and-VM/Complete-Guide-How-to-Increase-space-on-Linux-vmware/td-p/388872

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted , watch some videos or check some link.
And restart the VM